# How to change font size of a text in a text box using vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Sir, I want to convert a text line(ex: apple, banana, orange, guava) into a column(by making a new line for every word) & give 2nd, 4th  number font sizes bigger(+4) & bold in my PowerPoint project.
So I try the below code but it neither increase font size nor make it bold. Any solution will be appreciated.

```
Sub Custom_newLine()
Dim TextStrng As String
Dim Result() As String
Dim DisplayText As String
Dim osld As Slide
Dim tboxShp As Shape
Dim myTextbox As Shape
Dim fontSize As Integer
     
 Set osld = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
 Set tboxShp = osld.Shapes("Textbox1")
 
 TextStrng = tboxShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text 'Text=apple, banana, orange, guava
 fontSize = tboxShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size
  
 Result = Split(TextStrng, ",")
For i = LBound(Result()) To UBound(Result())    
  If i = 1 Or i = 3 Or i = 5 Then
    
        Set myTextbox = osld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=0, Top:=10, Width:=400, Height:=100)

     With myTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange
          .Text = Result(i)
       With .Font
        .Size = fontSize + 4
        .Bold = True
      End With
    
   End With
     Result(i) = myTextbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text
     myTextbox.Delete
 End If
        DisplayText = DisplayText & Result(i) & vbNewLine    
Next i         
   tboxShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DisplayText

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're new to VBA. Textbox1 would need to be in quotes, or the sub doesn't run at all. Rather than give you an easy answer, I'm going to tell you how to debug code so you can find the problems yourself.

The left side of the code listing window has a light gray bar. If you click inside that grey bar, the bar will display a brown dot and a brown bar will be drawn across the adjacent line of code. When you run the code, it will halt at that brown bar. Clicking beside the *TextStrng* line is a good spot.

Then by pressing the **F8** key, you can step through your code one line at a time. This will show you exactly what your code is doing at every step of the way. Hint: it's nothing like what you describe you're trying to do.

Doing this will show you that there are 2 problems. with the way your code is structured that is giving you unexpected results. They'll be fairly easy to find when stepping through.

Comment: sorry Sir I forgot to add quotes in Textbox1. It's my mistake but still did not give my result.

Comment: Please use the techniques I posted. Learning how to debug is an essential part of programming. You'll find your errors easily enough if you follow the method. I can correct your code, but you'll learn nothing from that.

Comment: Sir, I tried as you suggest but did not get any error message. But text changed to a column with the same size font &  without bold also.

Comment: I never said you would get an error message. I said that your code had errors. Did you not notice that every second word is displayed in bold in a text box near the upper left corner of the slide, and then it is deleted? Go through the code slowly, one line at a time and observe what actually happens, then contrast with what you say you want to happen.

Comment: Sir, I noticed the words displayed in bold with a larger font(which I required) in the upper left corner of the slide.
 I captured the formattted text("banana") in Result(i) & then deleted the word. I think when it displayed after newline created
 then it formated with former text format("apple") & not took format from Result(i)(ie "banana"; bold & larger font).

Comment: Yes! That's a good start. To me, it sounded like you wanted those words to be bolded, but in the original text box, instead a of a new text box in a different position. It that correct?

Comment: yes sir. I want those line text ie apple, banana, orange, guava to column structure using creating new lines in the same text box but the 2nd, 4th words will be bold & the font size will be bigger.